# How to use Many to Many Relationship posts#show In ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

in **Teams#model**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :postteams
  has_many :posts, :through => :postteams

end
```

in **Post#model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :postteams
  has_many :teams, :through => :postteams

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postteams
end
```

In **Postteam Model**

```
class Postteam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Through these relations, i finally succeed to make post with these multiple teams and also save these teams in database, like this

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giIMk.png)

here is my **post#controller**:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new

    @all_teams = Team.all
    @post_team = @post.postteams.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    params[:teams][:id].each do |team|

      if !team.empty?
        @post.postteams.build(:team_id => team)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_url, notice: 'Player was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_player
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, team_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Now I'm stuck here, How to show these **teams**, in **posts#show** page,

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>Team Names:</p>

.............what i add here, to show both these multi teams........
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXjw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over all `@post`'s `postteams` and display it's `name`/`title`/whatsoever:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>Team Names:</p>
  <% @post.postteams.each do |pt| %>
    <% = pt.name %> # or whatever attribute of postteam you want to display
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot Bro, I finally got multi teams, now one more help, Please take a look this link and you'll got want i Want

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097589/how-to-show-multi-teams-results-players-in-posts-ruby-on-rails

Its my second question, I need Both Teams, Teams results (which is Players) in same Post#View

Please tell me and I'm giving both these answers my best help and perfect answers list.. Thanks a lot BRO,, I saved my couple of days and help.

Comment: @SaurabhKamboj if that's solved, please mark the answer as accepted (checkmark). I'll take a look into your next question

Comment: Hey Andrey, I marked it, please help me, Otherwise this help is waste for me, because I'was not asking you this in this same question, because it will make you confuse. Thanks a lot, Just help me to show Players results in teams link

Comment: @SaurabhKamboj i'll take a look now

Comment: Thanks bro, I'll wait you ;-)