# How to Show Multi Teams Results (Players) in Posts! Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

How to Show Multi (**Teams**) Results (**Players**) in Posts

I Already got one **post** and both **Multi Teams** of this post **like in this pic**!!!

[image: post]

My previous question you can check out is [How to use Many to Many Relationship posts#show In ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094990/how-to-use-many-to-many-relationship-postsshow-in-ruby-on-rails). Now I use Teams and Players like this:

In **Players#Model**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :team
end
```

In **Teams#Model**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players

  has_many :postteams
  has_many :posts, :through => :postteams

end
```

In **Postteam#Model**

```
class Postteam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :team
end
```

**Now I want to show these Teams Results (Players) with** players#Controller **in these Teams like this pic example**

[image: players]

Comment: please provide some more info on where players info is stored and what is it exactly

Comment: Alright, I create players and teams through activeadmin, for more info, please take a look this link, 

http://matchcentre.starsports.com/cricket/indian-premier-league-2015-237/knightriders-vs-delhidaredevils-178062/scorecard/1

I want exactly same thing, on left side this link, you'll check 2 Teams, you'll see players list. I know its a simple way for you, to create this project! thanks my friend.